# QT Creator Disable displaying file path in file browser

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I move source and header files in `include` and `src` dirrectories. Then i define this dirrectories in VPATH and include files without specifying any directory.

[image]

After all of this, I want to see files in the File Browser panel as included directly (without any path), but I see relative paths anyway!

[image]

Is there some way to disable relative paths in File Browser panel?

P. S. I doesn't like "Simplify Tree" option, coz it place all headers and sources in one folder. This is uncomfortabel.

Comment: I have had this issue on Linux  , I found that project was in symbolic linked folder , I removed .user file and reopen project from its physical disk to fix  , i.e not from target link .. this seemed to cause relative path behavior ..

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots are all taken from "Projects" view, not from file view. The project view is meant to visualize the build system. Your build system has the files stored in a subfolder, so Creator will display that. Since the Projects view is used to add files into the project this is important: Which folder should a new file go into if that folder was not displayed?

It does not matter how you write the filenames into your .pro-file: Creator will get a list of absolute paths for all your sources -- as long as qmake/make can build your project that is:-)

Comment: If metter of destination folder is only one, then it's false. Coz `Project View` have option `Simplify Tree` (I can't see in which folder I add source), but it is uncomfortable option.